# cannot add a user and password to a google cloud sql database

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm having trouble adding a user to a google cloud sql database.  I have an app on google app engine.  I've setup a google cloud sql instance with the ip address of my own laptop computer.  My app engine app is setup to use the google cloud instance.

I go to the google developer console and select the app engine project.  I click "cloud sql".  I then click "access control" and select the "users" tab.

I click the "new user button".  I then enter the user name and password.  I then click the "OK" button.  Nothing happens after clicking the OK button several times and nothing happens.

I also tried selecting "advanced options" and click the OK button.  Nothing happens.  The only way to leave the popup box is clicking the "cancel" button.

I am running the developers console using windows 8 and internet explorer.  I'm sorry if I'm doing something stupid.  I've searched on-line and can't find any solutions.  Thank you.

Comment: Does it happen in other browsers?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue on IE11. I'm in the Cloud SQL team and I'll make sure it gets fixed, sorry about the bad user experience. Seems to be working fine on Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Thank you Juan for your quick response.  I was able to add a user using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

@ juan said, it seems a bug. So I would suggest you to file this bug on [PIT](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/), so that you can also have the track of the update for this bug.

Comment: He is correct I am also able to reproduce the bug on my side.